# SSIS packages stopped working after Oracle DB and Oracle Client upgrade

Tags: oracle, installation

We currently use SSIS for transferring data from Oracle Server and load into SQL Server.
The Oracle Server has now been upgraded to 19c from 11g after which we are unable to connect to

```
OLD Versions of softwares used
Oracle Server Version : 11g
Microsoft Visual Studio : V14.0.250420.01 update 3
Oracle SSIS version  : 14.0.800.900
Attunity Connector version : 2/3/4/5
```

Oracle is now upgraded to 19c and now the SSIS packages have stopped working.

I tried upgrading the Oracle Client to 19c but it did not help. Please guide

Comment: There really isn't much to go on here in terms of detail, and not sure a forum on code development is the best place for your question. This is more a question for Oracle Support.

Comment: "Stopped working" is not found any any error reference that I know of.  Surely, when it "stopped working" it emitted an actual error message somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio stopped working because the Attunity Connector version is not compatible with Oracle 19c Client. For now I have uninstalled the Oracle 19c Client and reinstalled both 11g and 12c clients to make everything work. We are currently upgrading the Visual Studio to next version to make everything work together.